# Measure Theory Conjecture: Continuity Preserving Measure of Special Sets

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the unit square $[0,1]^{2}$ such that:

> $A\cap B = \emptyset$
>
> $A\cup B = [0,1]^{2}$.
>
> $A$ and $B$ are both dense in $[0,1]^{2}$.

Suppose there exists a continuous function $f:[0,1]^{2}\to[0,1]$ such that:

> $f(A)\cap f(B) = \emptyset$
>
> $f(A)\cup f(B) = [0,1]$.
>
> $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are both dense in $[0,1]$.
>
> $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are both Borel and so Lebesgue measurable.
>
> $\lambda_{1}(f(A)) = 1$, $\lambda_{1}(f(B)) = 0$ (where $\lambda_{1}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Can we say anything about $\lambda_{2}(A)$ and $\lambda_{2}(B)$ (where $\lambda_{2}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$)? This makes sense to talk about as $f$ is continuous and so the preimages $A$ and $B$ are Borel.

This arises from a homework question that was more specific about what $A$ and $B$ were. The answer was that $\lambda_{2}(A) = 1$ and $\lambda_{2}(B) = 0$. Is it true in this more general situation though?

Comment: What is the "more specific" context you are referring to? I think in the  case the answer is no. You can pick $C \subset [0,1]$ a non-zero measure Cantor set and set $A = C \times [0,1]$, $B_0 =C^c \times [0,1]$. Let $f(x,y) = \varphi(x)$ and $\varphi: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be an Cantor-type increasing function with $\varphi(C^c)$ being the dyadic numbers. Those $A$,$B$ satisfy all the properties except for the density, but by iterating the Cantor set construction in the excluded intervals you can probably fix that.

Comment: The question was $A =\{(x, y) : x-y \notin \mathbb{Q}\} $. Are you sure the images of your $A$ and $B$ are Borel?